# Easiest way to clean email address in python

Tags: python, email, data-cleaning

I am having issues with emails address and with a small correction, they are can be converted to valid email addresses.

For Ex:

```
%20adi@gmail.com, --- Not valid
'sam@tell.net,  --- Not valid
(hi@telligen.com),  --- Not valid
(gii@weerte.com),  --- Not valid
:qwert34@embright.com,  --- Not valid
//24adifrmaes@microsot.com  --- Not valid
tellei@apple.com    ---  valid
...
```

I could write "if else", but if a new email address comes with new issues, I need to write "ifelse " and update every time.

What is the best way to clean all these small issues, some python packes or regex? PLease suggest.

Comment: do you want to delete the ones with the wrong shape or correct them ?

Comment: correct them please

Comment: okay, check my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this (I basically check if the elements in the email are alpha characters or a point, and remove them if not so):

```
emails = [
    'sam@tell.net', 
    '(hi@telligen.com)', 
    '(gii@weerte.com)',  
    ':qwert34@embright.com',  
    '//24adifrmaes@microsot.com',
    'tellei@apple.com'
    ]

def correct_email_format(email):
    return ''.join(e for e in email if (e.isalnum() or e in ['.', '@']))

for email in emails:
    corrected_email = correct_email_format(email)
    print(corrected_email)
```

output:

```
sam@tell.net
hi@telligen.com
gii@weerte.com
qwert34@embright.com
24adifrmaes@microsot.com
tellei@apple.com
```

Comment: in the output it is missing "@"

Comment: okay, corrected it! (added the @ in the exceptions)

Comment: @Firelord yes you are right, updated it again!

Comment: You may want to whitelist `+`.  a+b@example.com is not the same as ab@example.com.  It's fairly common (gmail supports it, or at least used to).

Comment: You may want to support addresses with a `-` or `_` etc.  It's complicated, and I found in practice you need a rule based approach.

Answer (score 1):

Data clean-up is messy but I found the approach of defining a set of rules to be an easy way to manage this (order of the rules matters):

```
rules = [
        lambda s: s.replace('%20', ' '),
        lambda s: s.strip(" ,'"),
]

addresses = [
        '%20adi@gmail.com,',
        'sam@tell.net,'
]

for a in addresses:
    for r in rules:
        a = r(a)
    print(a)
```

and here is the resulting output:

```
adi@gmail.com
sam@tell.net
```

Make sure you write a test suite that covers both invalid and valid data.  It's easy break, and you may be tweaking the rules often.

While I used lambda for the rules above, it can be an arbitrary complex function that accepts and return a string.

Comment: Thank you, How would I. expand this 

lambda s: s.replace('%20', ' ') to other replacement string,? just add another lambda?

Comment: Yes, just add another rule.  With your example data you also want to add more characters to the `strip()` lambda to remove more of the leading and trailing characters.

Comment: You can try to validate the address in the end, but you don't really now if the address is valid till you try sending an email to it.  You build up a blacklist of those by processing bounces.

Comment: @AllanWind although I didn't try this functionality, [email-validator](https://pypi.org/project/email-validator/) features validating if the email can actually be sent to a domain or not. So no need to wait for bouncing emails to process them into denylist.

Comment: @Firelord The feature would use the smtp `vrfy` and/or `expn`.  The remote email server may or may not support that.  Also, it will not tell you if the mailbox is full, or misconfigured (alias exist on this mail server, but forwards to a non-existing account etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a complicated one if you have more different test cases, ie., `email@email.com.`, `,,email@email.com.@_)` or `..email@email.com@@@`. Still, you can strip them but it cannot be limited to what is to be stripped at the end and beginning.

**Note:** Email addresses with numbers and _ are valid too.

```
emails = [
    'sam@tell.net', 
    '(hi@telligen.com)', 
    '(gii@weerte.com)',  
    ':qwert34@embright.com',  
    '//24adifrmaes@microsot.com',
    'tellei@apple.com'
    ]

def clean(email):
  return ''.join(filter(lambda x: ord(x) >= 65 or x in ['.', '@', '_'], email))

for email in emails:
  print(clean(email))
```

**Output:**

```
sam@tell.net
hi@telligen.com
gii@weerte.com
qwert@embright.com
adifrmaes@microsot.com
tellei@apple.com
```